# css3 flex-box internet explorer not aligning properly

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I've been following this [tutorial video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1uzS6PAjuc) it shows everything clearly about flexible boxes in css3. i dont have any problem on mozilla or chrome. But  box is placed just below of section box in internet explorer. demo can be found [here](http://www.mreo.net/html5/index.html) (if you view on mozilla,ie you can see the difference).  here is the html codes which ive been playing with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> First html5 </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mainnew.css" />
</head>

<body> 
<div id="big_wrapper">
<header id="top_header">
<h1> Welcome to html5 </h1>
</header>

<nav id="top_menu">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Tutorials</li>
<li>Podcast</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div id="new_div">
<section id="main_section">
<article>
<header>
<hgroup>
<h1>Title of article</h1>
<h2>Subtitle for article!</h2>
</hgroup>
</header>
<p>This is the best article eva!</p>
<footer>
<p>- writtern by Emre Caglar </p>
</footer>
</article>

<article>
<header>
<hgroup>
<h1>Title of article2</h1>
<h2>Subtitle for article2!</h2>
</hgroup>
</header>
<p>This is the best article eva!</p>
<footer>
<p>- writtern by Emre Caglar </p>
</footer>
</article>
</section>

<aside id="side_news">
<h4>News</h4>
Emre has a new dog
</aside>

</div>


<footer id="the_footer">
Copyright mreonet 2012
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and css codes

```
body{
        width:100%;
        display:-webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        -webkit-box-pack:center;
        -moz-box-pack:center;
        box-pack:center;
    }
    #big_wrapper {
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin:20px 0px;
        display:-webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        -moz-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        box-orient: vertical;
        -moz-box-flex: 1.0; 
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        box-flex: 1;

    }
    #top_header {
        background:yellow;
        border: 3px solid black;
        padding:20px;
    }
    #top_menu { 
        border:red;
        background:blue;
        color:white;
    }
    #top_menu li {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #new_div { 
        display:-webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        -webkit-box-orient:horizantal;
        -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
        box-orient: horizontal;

    }
    #main_section {
        border:1px solid blue;
        margin:20px;
        padding: 20px;
        -moz-box-flex: 1.0; 
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        box-flex: 1;

    }
    #side_news {
        border:1px solid red;
        width:220px;
        margin:20px 0px;
        padding:30px;
        background:#66cccc;
```

I've also noticed that when i view this page on ie8 it is not taking css styling. i am really new on html5 and might make silly mistakes..

Can any one help me on this. BTW this is my first question and if i miss anything let me know and sory about it.

Comment: Welcome on SO :) Are you testing the whole thing on IE8 or IE9/10? IE8 was (at last) the first version quite OK with CSS2.1 but has very little support of CSS3 and none for HTML5 except the doctype (not counting features coming from MSIE like @font-face ...) EDIT: and thus need activation of JS and polyfills to emulate these features. Details are on http://caniuse.com

Comment: Thanks first of all :) i've tested on ie8 (no styling at all) and ie9 (as mentioned incorrect alignment). what kind of JS and pollyfills is needed. I dont have any ideas about them .. can you give me an example

Answer (score 1):

Flexible Box model is not yet supported in IE.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-flex.asp

Comment: please [don't link to w3schools](http://w3fools.com). 

here's a better answer: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Flexible Box model is supported in IE10.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

In fact, I have been playing with browser prefixes the week.

http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/#test-drive

Answer (score 0):

As @Ravi mentioned, IE [doesn't natively support `flex-box`](http://caniuse.com/flexbox). Here's a [polyfill](http://flexiejs.com/) you can use to enable it in IE.

Answer (score 0):

flex box is supported in IE. However IE 1o is based on March 22, 2012 version of the Flexbox Working Draft. Use ms-flex-direction to achieve orientation. Row for horizontal and column for vertical. See here for details of how to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx

e.g.

```
body
{   
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  border: blue; 
  width: 100%;
  height:500px
}

#box1 {
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    background: black;
    border: black;
    border: 1px solid black
}

#box2 {
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    border: red;
    border: 1px solid black
}
```